# Perl: Reading binary file one byte at a time

Tags: perl, file, input, binary, byte

I'm writing a tool that needs to read a binary file one byte at a time, process each byte, and potentially take some action depending on the processed value. But for some reason the values Perl is getting are not the same as the data in the file. I'm using code similar to this (stripped down for brevity, but this still exhibits the issue):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $bytesToProcess = 16;
my $fileName = 'datafile.bin';

print "Processing $bytesToProcess bytes...\n";

open FILE, "<:raw", $fileName or die "Couldn't open $fileName!";

for my $offset (0 .. $bytesToProcess - 1)
{
    my $oneByte;
    read(FILE, $oneByte, 1) or die "Error reading $fileName!";
    printf "0x%04X\t0x%02X\n", $offset, $oneByte;
}

close FILE;
```

Input values (first 16 bytes of data file): `50 53 4D 46 30 30 31 35 00 00 70 00 07 3F 10 00`

Output:

```
Processing 16 bytes...
0x0000  0x00
0x0001  0x00
0x0002  0x00
0x0003  0x00
0x0004  0x00
0x0005  0x00
0x0006  0x01
0x0007  0x05
0x0008  0x00
0x0009  0x00
0x000A  0x00
0x000B  0x00
0x000C  0x00
0x000D  0x00
0x000E  0x00
0x000F  0x00
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: seems the bytes are being interpreted as ASCII chars (`0x35 = '5' => 5`)

Comment: Which platform are you on?  Windows or non-Windows (Unix-ish) is likely to be the significant difference.  I'm not sure that it will actually matter, but may as well cover the bases.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!! This would have pointed out the problem immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`read` returns the byte as the char `"\x50"`, not the number `0x50`. Change the `printf` line to

```
printf "0x%04X\t0x%02X\n", $offset, ord $oneByte;
```

Another option is to use `unpack 'c', $oneByte`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Do I need to use chr() if I want to write the bytes back out to a file?

Comment: @DarkMorford: Yes, or `pack` for `unpack`.